# Where to find the .vim directory?

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

I'm trying to find out my .vim file which is a hidden file and that should be in my home , I want to install a vim plugin and for that i need to access the plugin folder which is in .vim file. I'm unable to find it out. I used terminal but I found this

```
amitwebhero@AmitKali:~$ ~/.vim
bash: /home/amitwebhero/.vim: No such file or directory
```

Try to tell me where i can find it

Comment: Then create it.

Comment: okay, but creating a new will work?

Comment: I use vim so i must have somewhere .vim or .vimrc directory in my home right?

Comment: You are trying to *run* `~/.vim` as a program, no wonder that fails. Do a `ls -a ~/.vim`, or even `find -name .vim -print`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not have a `.vim` directory or `.vimrc` file in your home directory the default ones in `/etc/vim` will be used instead.

To override the values in `/etc/vim` for your user you should create a `.vim` directory and `.vimrc` file in your home directory.